# Pine Script Simple Moving Average Plot Issue

Tags: pine-script

I am using the below script to plot SMA for length 200 in a 5 Minute Chart.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="MA Banknifty", shorttitle="MY SMA", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

length = 200
source = close

sma_200 = ta.sma(source, length)

plot(sma_200, color=color.rgb(243, 33, 33), linewidth=2, title="SMA(200)")
```

The calculated value is correct, but the line (red plot line) plots different values. The blue plotline is in-built SMA function and it shows the same values as my script. Where am I wrong in plotting my SMA?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue since early morning today. The scaling is set to no scale for some reason when you add a new indicator.

Change it to "Pinned to right scale" and it will be alright.

[image]